# Structured binding fails to compile

Tags: c++

Consider following code snippet which introduces a custom `Test` type with support to structured binding:

```
struct Test {
    int member;
};

template<>
struct std::tuple_size<::Test>
{
    static constexpr size_t value = 1;
};

template<>
struct std::tuple_element<0, ::Test>
{
    using type = int;
};

template <size_t Index>
const int& get(const Test& test)
{
    // Omit Index for the sake of brevity
    return test.member;
}

int main() {
    Test test = Test{1234};
    auto [member] = test;
    return 0;
}
```

The code does not compile with following error:

> error: binding reference of type ‘std::tuple_element<0, Test>::type&’
> {aka ‘int&’} to ‘const int’ discards qualifiers

According to my understanding the structured binding should expand to (test is converted to xvalue and passed to `get` function):

> In these initializer expressions, e is an lvalue if the type of the
> entity e is an lvalue reference (this only happens if the
> ref-qualifier is & or if it is && and the initializer expression is an
> lvalue) and an xvalue otherwise (this effectively performs a kind of
> perfect forwarding), i is a std::size_t prvalue, and  is always
> interpreted as a template parameter list.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

```
Test test = Test{1234};
Test hidden = Test(test);
const int& member = get<0UL>(static_cast<Test &&>(hidden));
```

which compiles fine. However, it looks like the const qualifier is left out and the `member`'s type is `int&` which for obvious reasons cannot compile and produce similar error message.

Comment: That `const` in the error message is a hint... Try `auto const [member] = test;` instead. Type-deduction with `auto` tend to disregard qualifiers.

Comment: yep, but why lack of `const` makes a difference there. I cannot get it... Type deduction with `auto` should affect only the hidden variable, shouldn't it?

Comment: `tuple_element` says that the type is `int`, but `get` says it is `const int`. Might confuse the compiler. The real `tuple` provides several specializations of each.

Comment: Adding `template <std::size_t Index> int& get(Test&& test)` fixes the issue too [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rM76MPKbb)

Comment: But why do you expect `const` binding? The hidden variable is not `const`, so `member` neither

Comment: So how is the type inferred? Isn't it just return type of a viable `get` call?

Comment: For the tuple or tuple-like structure binding case, the `auto` applies to the hidden variable.  You will either need to provide the `int&& get(&&)` getter, or change from `auto` (using a hidden variable) to `auto const&` (no hidden variable, using `test` directly).

Comment: As the `auto` applies to the hidden variable, which language rule prevents the code from being compiled? In this case the `auto` introduces a copy which is then taken as `const&` in order to produce `const int&` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than `const int &member`, you get `int &member`:

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding#Case_2:_binding_a_tuple-like_type)

> [the type is] reference to `std::tuple_element<i, E>::type`, ... lvalue reference if its corresponding initializer is an lvalue, rvalue reference otherwise

Where `E` is `std::remove_reference_t<decltype((hidden))>`, aka `Test`. And the "corresponding initializer" is what your `get()` returns.

`std::tuple_element` automatically propagates `const` from its template parameter to the resulting type, but it doesn't help, because `E` isn't `const` in the first place.

---

This boils down to `get` not being written correctly. You need 4 overloads, for all combinations of `const`, non-`const`, `&` and `&&`.

Those can be compacted to:

```
template <size_t Index, typename T>
requires std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, Test>
auto &&get(T &&test)
{
    return std::forward<T>(test).member;
}
```

Alternatively, if you intend your type to be read-only when using tuple protocol, force `tuple_element` to always be `const`:

```
template<>
struct std::tuple_element<0, ::Test>
{
    using type = const int;
};
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: How does it work with const values then? If i replaced the main line with `const auto& [member] = t;` then E would be deduced as `const Test` and the `std::tuple_element<i, E>::type` type wouldn't be deduced as there is no specialization for `const Test`. However the code compiles fine.

Comment: @Mati The standard provides a default `tuple_elemenr<const T>` specialization, which returns `const tuple_element<T>::type`. That's what I meant by *"automatically propagates const"*.

Comment: Now I got it! :)

Answer (score 1):

The reference-qualifier (lvalue vs rvalue) for the introduced variables are deduced from the initializer (i.e. your `get` overload), but the `const`-qualifications aren't. Except for the reference qualification, the whole type is retrieved from `tuple_element`, which in your case isn't `const int`, but just `int`.

The relevant rule in the standard is in [sentence 8 of [dcl.struct.bind]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.struct.bind#4.sentence-8). In your cppreference link it is mentioned above your quote:

> For each identifier, a variable whose type is "reference to std::tuple_element<i, E>::type" is introduced: [...]